# Laravel blank screen on cPanel

Tags: php, laravel, apache, cpanel, shared-hosting

i have a problem with laravel and shared hosting,

i've uploaded whole thing to a server root, copied public folder into public_html and changed require paths in index.php

if i leave .htaccess as it is i get error 500, apache errors says:

```
public_html/.htaccess: Options not allowed here
```

so if i comment out line with "Options -MultiViews -Indexes" error 500 disapears on screen, but in the browser console says still error 500, apache or laravel.log say no errors,

i've set permissions to 777 on everything i could think of, and when i

```
echo "Something here"
```

in index.php i can see it but nothing else, a blank screen

i have no SSH access, please help

Comment: What is your PHP version and laravel version, this blank screen error occurs most times because the shared hosting server might be running a lower version of PHP required for the laravel version

Comment: I'm also having same problem. Currently I use Laravel 5.8 and php 5.6

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure public folder already in the right place (as you set on domain setting).
then clean cache files.

hope it help.
Thanks